# Remove escape characters from string using c#

Tags: c#, string

```
string str = @"*[@Name=\'Cd.exe\' and @ControlType=\'ControlType.Button\' and @AutomationId=\'C:\bin\Sp.exe\']";
var output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str);
```

I want to remove escape characters from above string but in above string contains **FilePath** also So how should i handle it

Above code is throwing exception below

```
ArgumentOutOfRange Exception
parsing "*[@Name=\'Cd.exe\' and @ControlType=\'ControlType.Button\' and @AutomationId=\'C:\bin\Sp.exe\']" - Unrecognized escape sequence \S.
```

Comment: Can't you just replace `\'` with `'`?

Comment: You want to `str = str.Replace(@"\'", "'")`

Comment: No use same error

Comment: you have to **escape your backslashes** by replacing "\" in your path with "\\". otherwise, the compiler is trying to parse `\S`. which it is ***telling you*** in the exception.

Comment: what output do you expect? `*[@Name='Cd.exe' and @ControlType='ControlType.Button' and @AutomationId='C:\bin\Sp.exe']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is invalid. If is is supposed to contain escaped Regex characters then file paths have to be escaped as well. For example:

```
@AutomationId='C:\\bin\\Sp\\.exe'
```

Backslash `\` has to be escaped, to avoid interpreting `\S` as special character. Dot `.` has to be escaped as well.

Additionally, single quote `'` characters is not escaped in Regex syntax: [Character Escapes in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions#character-escapes-in-net)

It seems to me that you are trying to unescape JavaScript string using Regex unescape? That won't work.

Most likely you just need this:

```cs
string str = @"*[@Name=\'Cd.exe\' and @ControlType=\'ControlType.Button\' and @AutomationId=\'C:\bin\Sp.exe\']";
var output = str.Replace("\\'", "'");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(output);

// Debug output:
*[@Name='Cd.exe' and @ControlType='ControlType.Button' and @AutomationId='C:\bin\Sp.exe']
```